# replace 20A switch with 16A switch

Tags: switches, amperage

On a space heater, I replaced a 20A DPST switch with a 16A one I found at radio shack.  I am unsure about the amperage of the circuit itself (how to find this?) but I'm assuming it's 20A or else the company would have bought a cheaper switch.  Seems to be working now, and I have a 20A switch on its way, but am I going to burn down the house in the interim?

In other words, I know I'm currently using the wrong switch, but would you consider it dangerous to leave this heater on until I get the proper switch?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve a down vote. The actual act of replacing the relay might, but not the question.

Comment: Why is it off-topic?

Comment: It's nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: It might be on-topic at DIY.SE, but I have a feeling that they have a question similar to this already.

Answer (score 8):

Replacing a 20 A switch with a 16 A switch without knowing anything else is a ***REALLY BAD IDEA***.

Chances are you won't burn your house down, but how lucky do you feel?  Fortunately, 25% overcurrent thru a switch is *unlikely* to do more than burn out the contacts such that the switch either won't close properly anymore or weld the contacts shut so that it is permanently on.  If the switch is in a metal box so that nothing too bad would happen if it reached the melting point of plastic, you *probably* won't burn your house down.

Even if the space heater doesn't draw more than 16 A, you still have a problem.  Suppose stuff happens (which it regularly does to space heaters, they are one of the leading causes of house fires and electrocutions) so that the power wires get shorted.  You want the breaker to trip to shut off the circuit.  This might not happen if the switch is a weaker link than the breaker.  Instead of the breaker popping, the switch might catch fire.  In general, it's a good idea to use a switch rated for at least the trip current of whatever power segment it is on.

To paraphrase Dirty Harry: *Do you feel lucky?  Well do you, punk?  Go ahead, use a 16 A switch.  **Make my day***.

Comment: @Ben: It looks like Kellenjb already fixed the typo.

Comment: Good to know, thank you.. I was in fact feeling quite  _unlucky_ :)  Not only is the housing plastic, it's reeaally cheap feeling.  Will wait for the proper switch.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, if you were to use a 16a circuit breaker instead of a 20a, the breaker would just keep tripping. It's the same thing as using a 15a or 20a for multiple plugs. If you have too much power drawing off a single breaker, it will trip. So, if you can use the heater and the breaker doesn't you should be fine. Although, using that breaker with anything else while the heater is on will most likely trip the switch.

Comment: The question doesn't mention circuit breakers anywhere…